# python equivalent to ruby bundler package

Tags: python, bundler, easy-install

I'm trying to deploy a python application which has a lot of dependencies and can either be installed by easy_install or pip, but the environment i deploy to is behind firewall and does not have access to internet. So i wonder if python has something like ruby bundler's ['package'](http://bundler.io/bundle_package.html) functionality, which can cache all *.egg and dependencies and then install them locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out easy_install already has a solution, [install-on-un-networked-machines](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#installing-on-un-networked-machines), but it is not perfect for C-extension python eggs because it requires the OS and arch on source machine and target machine  are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). There should be options to include *.egg